# Замена \\ на \ в Python

Tags: python, replace, замена

Всем привет! Если вопрос глупый, заранее извините. В поиске ничего не нашел.

Есть 2 переменные:

```
x1 = '\u0421\u0415\u041a\u0420\u0415\u0422'
x2 = '\\u0421\\u0415\\u041a\\u0420\\u0415\\u0422'

print(x1) #СЕКРЕТ
print(x2) #\u0421\u0415\u041a\u0420\u0415\u0422
```

В первом случае все работает отлично. Но в моей функции переменная x2 получает строку со значением

```
'\\u0421\\u0415\\u041a\\u0420\\u0415\\u0422'
```

Как мне `x2` привести к виду `x1`? Да, напрашиваются очевидные вещи вроде

```
x3 = x2.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

Но они ведут к такому же результату:

```
print(x3) #\u0421\u0415\u041a\u0420\u0415\u0422
```

Comment: Что-то вы не совсем так написали. Вторая строка печатается как `\С\Е\К\Р\Е\Т`, наверное у вас всё же там другое кол-во бэкслэшей.

Comment: Да, я когда печатал, отображалось нормальное ко-во бэкслэшей. Видимо я неправильно форматировал. Но затем модератор исправил, и бэкслэшей стало больше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ для текущего, т.е. **измененного** вопроса:

```
x2.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

Объясню после подтверждения, что суть вашего вопроса уже не будет изменена.

---

*Объяснение:*

Смотря на последовательность знаков в вашей строке, вижу, что она как будто приехала на ваш компьютер из другого компьютера (может быть, из сервера на Интернете):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему?**

Потому что это знакомый образец одной из кодировок символов (напр. букв) в последовательность байтов, так называема **«екранированный Юникод»** *(Unicode escape).*

**Зачем кодировка?**

Потому что дорожка от компьютера до компьютера очень узка — данные могут ее проходить только **байт за байтом**.

Но байт может содержать только 256 разных значений — очень мало для букв и символов всех языков мира! И так, большинство символов нужно заменить последовательностей двух, трех и иногда и более байтов. Другими словами, отдельные символы нужно **кодировать**.

После пути к вашему компьютеру нужно последовательность байтов **декодировать**.

**Как была последовательность байтов декодирована в вашем компьютере?**

Плохо. Байт за байтом: `\`, затем `u`, затем `0`, затем `4`, и тд. (Как будто никак, более точно, как последовательность ASCII символов, т.к. байт просто целое число от 0 до 255).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы получили строку 36 «американских» символов вместо 6 символов «наших».

(Между апострофами или кавычками нужно в Питоне один символ `\` *записать* как пару `\\`, но всё равно это только форма записи **одного** `\`.)

**Что с этим делать?**

Как будто приготовить их обратно к отправлению на другой компютер - закодировать их обратно **в байты**:

```
x2.encode()         # примениться стандартный кодер utf_8, пригодный тоже для ASCII
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но никуда их не посылаем — наоборот, делаем вид, что мы их только что приняли из другого компьютера:

- На результат `x2.encode()` типа `bytes` ...
- ... мы применим на этот раз правильный декодер `'unicode_escape'`:

  ```
  x2.encode()   .decode('unicode_escape')
  ```

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- чтобы получит строку `"СЕКРЕТ"` типа `str`.

---

*Примечания:*

1. Кодер / декодер, символы / байты, тип `str` / тип `bytes`

   - В направлении **от компьютера** применяется **кодер**, который превращает *символы в последовательность байтов* (тип `str` ⇾ тип `bytes`),
   - в направлении **в компьютер** применяется **декодер**, который превращает *последовательность байтов в символы* (тип `bytes` ⇾ тип `str`)
2. [Исчерпывающее руководство по Юникоду и кодировке символов в Python](https://tproger.ru/translations/unicode-and-encoding-python-guide/).

Comment: Да! Работает, и этот вариант даже проще, чем предложил CrazyElf. Надо же, всего один лишний бэкслэш, и решение кардинально изменилось. Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: В питоне 2 всё работает и без encode, в питоне 3 как-то тупо сделано :(

Comment: @andreymal, это не совсем тупо. В Питоне 2 вы можете кодированную строку (по ошибке) вместо декодирования *снова кодировать*, в Питоне 3 нельзя.

Comment: @MarianD то, что по ошибке больше нельзя — хорошо, а то, что намеренно тоже больше нельзя (как в данном вопросе) — тупо)

Comment: @andreymal, в Питоне 3 невозможно по определению работать со строками как с последовательностями байтов, что по моему хорошо (быть независимым от внутренней имплементации типа `str`). Но я вас понимаю — вы наверно долго работали в Питоне 2. :-)

Comment: Отлично, что есть простой вариант. Питон вообще такой язык, что какое решение не напиши, всегда найдётся ещё более простое )

Comment: Я понял, вы мне очень помогли. Спасибо большое

Comment: @Алексей Комаров, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ для **первоначального** вопроса, в котором было

`x2 = '\\\u0421\\\u0415\\\u041a\\\u0420\\\u0415\\\u0422'`:

```
x3 = x2.replace('\\', '')
```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
x1 = '\u0421\u0415\u041a\u0420\u0415\u0422'
```

Значение переменной `x1` состоит из 6 знаков, выраженных в коде Юникод как
`\u0421`, `\u0415`, `\u041a`, `\u0420`, `\u0415`, `\u0422`:

```
>>> print(x1)
СЕКРЕТ
```

Теперь `x2`:

```
x2 = '\\\u0421\\\u0415\\\u041a\\\u0420\\\u0415\\\u0422'
```

Так как `"\\"` интерпретируется как один знак `\`, `x2` состоит из 12 знаков:
`\`, `\u0421`, `\`, `\u0415`, `\`, `\u041a`, `\`, `\u0420`, `\`, `\u0415`, `\`, `\u0422`:

```
>>> print(x2)
\С\Е\К\Р\Е\Т
```

Видимо, нужно только удалить все знаки `\`, например заменой всякого знака `\` на пустую строку.

Так как

- строку с одним знаком `\` нужно в Питоне писать как `'\\'`,
- пустую строку как `''`

команда будет такой, как я написал в начале моего ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Но я ошибся при форматировании поста. На самом деле слэшей должно быть меньше, и в этом вся сложность. Я исправил пост, теперь слэшей правильное количество и ваш способ уже не подходит

Answer (score 1):

Ответ для **первоначального** вопроса, в котором было

`x2 = '\\\u0421\\\u0415\\\u041a\\\u0420\\\u0415\\\u0422'`:

Возможно применить метод [`translate()`](https://pythonim.ru/string/translate-python) (и возможно стандартную функцию [`ord()`](https://pythoninfo.ru/osnovy/str-python)) для удаления всех знаков `\`:

```
x3 = x2.translate({ord("\\"): None})
```

или просто

```
x3 = x2.translate({92: None})
```

потому что `ord("\\") == 92` (читай: Юникод номер знака `\` равен 92).

Параметр метода `translate()` это так называема *переводная таблица*. В нашем простом случае мы используем словарь с одним элементом — значение `None` для ключа `92` поручает удалить все знаки с Юникод номером `92`, т.е. все знаки `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если последняя правка верна, то так можно:

```py
print(''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in x2.split('\\u') if x))
# СЕКРЕТ
```

То есть убираем все `\u`, а то, что между ними, переводим из 16-ричного вида в обычное число и потом в символ с таким кодом.

Comment: А как насчёт варианта `x2 = 'foo \\u0241 bar \\U0001f512'` ?

Comment: это работает! Это для меня очень сложно, но спасибо! Попробую разобраться